# Change function in javascript object

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Hello I wonder how to make something like it's in jQuery UI. For example

```
var myValue;
$('slider').slider({
    min: opts['min'],
    max: opts['max'],
    value: opts['value'],
    step: opts['step'],
    change: function(event, ui){
        myValue = ui.value;
    }
});
```

So, I'd like to create change function in my object which will work in the same way.

```
var myValue;
    distance.init(selector, '', 
        function(valueWhichIgetAfterChange){ // it will be change function in my object
            myValue = valueWhichIgetAfterChange;
        }
    );
```

In summary I'd like to init my object with a possibility to send there selector, options and change function where 'valueWhichIgetAfterChange' will always have the current value which will be sent by object after any change (when input will be changed for example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So they way they do that is to merge two objects together using [`$.extend()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/).

```
function passMeAnObject(obj){
  var settings = {
      setting1: 'first',
      setting2: 'second',
      setting3: 'third'
  };
  $.extend(settings,obj);
}

passMeAnObject({setting1:'fourth'});
```

This would update the `setting1` property, leaving the other two as unchanged or 'default'.

Comment: I'm sorry I was doing another project. I know how to merge two objects but I dont' know what happens there that ui object is always updated despite of the fact that it's sending as an attribute of a function. It doesn't seem to be something that is returned by function. It's just here: $('.slider').slider({change: function(event, ui){...}